# XSL display similar nodes same level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml data like this.

```
    <commentList>
     <item>
        <comment_id>2</comment_id>
        <discussion_id>3</discussion_id>
        <replyTo>0</replyTo>
        <Text>This is a test comment</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>3</comment_id>
        <discussion_id>3</discussion_id>
        <replyTo>0</replyTo>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>4</comment_id>
        <discussion_id>3</discussion_id>
        <replyTo>2</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to This is a test comment</Text>
     </item>
    </commentList>
```

replyTo - parent comment id (0 = root)

replyTo goes maximum one level.

I just want to display comment and relevant replies first. then next comment and replies and so on. Is there a best way to archive this? Thanks in advance.

Expected output as per above question.

```
This is a test comment
- Reply to This is a test comment
Hello
```

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: By "display", do you mean in a browser while visiting a web page?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service where you post your requirements and someone implements them for you without charge. We are here to help you with your existing code, so please post it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Expected output like this. 1. This is a test comment  2. Reply to This is a test comment 3. Hello

Comment: @Perera1987 Please edit your question and add the expected output **as code**.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry i was try to simplified my question so everyone can understand. I can post my entire code but it contains lots of unwanted data. Thanks

Comment: No, that's not useful either. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and more generally http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. -- Yes, the "restart from scratch" part is actually serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's convenient to use a [**key**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to link items to their replies.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="replies" match="item" use="replyTo" />

<xsl:template match="/commentList">
    <!-- select starter items -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[replyTo=0]"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="replyTo > 0">
        <xsl:text>- </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- append replies -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('replies', comment_id)"/>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This places no limit to the number of levels. For example, given the following test input:

**XML**

```
<commentList>
      <item>
        <comment_id>1</comment_id>
        <replyTo>0</replyTo>
        <Text>One</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>2</comment_id>
        <replyTo>0</replyTo>
        <Text>Two</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>3</comment_id>
        <replyTo>1</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to One</Text>
     </item>
    <item>
        <comment_id>4</comment_id>
        <replyTo>2</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to Two</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>5</comment_id>
        <replyTo>1</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to One</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>6</comment_id>
        <replyTo>3</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to Three</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>7</comment_id>
        <replyTo>3</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to Three</Text>
     </item>
     <item>
        <comment_id>8</comment_id>
        <replyTo>4</replyTo>
        <Text>Reply to Four</Text>
     </item>
</commentList>
```

the **result** will be:

```
One
- Reply to One
- Reply to Three
- Reply to Three
- Reply to One
Two
- Reply to Two
- Reply to Four
```